# Events that we register with the OS for any files added to the System

Tags: linux, windows, macos, winapi, filesystems

I want to process certain types of files lets say pdfs, whenever they get copied/downloaded to the system.

Is there any why that we can register with OS for listening to this kind of events.

I am ready to implement separate solutions for windows, mac and linux if required.

Comment: @xearinox i meant that both in osx and windows, what are the solutions. they can be different.

Comment: Question is unclear, what you mean added to the system?

Comment: In the body of the code i said, copied. Now improved it to copied/downloaded. I mean when we introduce a new file, i want to process it.

Comment: Where you want register? If you want notification try copy hook handler, or in lowest level you might try file system filter driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows has a concept of filesystem filter drivers (kernel-mode ones). Using it your software can intercept any filesystem operations and alter the data or just perform some action (or even prevent the operation). You can write such driver yourself or use our [CallbackFilter](https://www.eldos.com/cbflt/) library which includes a pre-created driver and provides an API for use in user-mode.

The alternative approach on windows is to use [FindFirstChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364417%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) system function to register for notification. This function works differently from the filter driver.

MacOS X doesn't have a concept of filter drivers but they have [FSEvents](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/FSEvents_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/kFSEventStreamCreateFlagFileEvents) API.

Update: (missed the linux part) on Linux [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) exists.

Comment: On Windows, there is also [`SHChangeNotifyRegister`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762120.aspx).

Comment: @RemyLebeau A good comment about SHChangeNotifyRegister can be found here: http://qualapps.blogspot.com/2010/05/understanding-readdirectorychangesw.html